# The photos program for Windows 10 won't let me crop - I crop it but it won't save the crop

Tags: windows, images, photos, crop

I click towards the top right to open Crop & Rotate. I crop the photo to the dimensions I want. I press Save a copy. Then I save - and if I save over the original file or I make a new file, it is still NOT cropped. What am I missing? Some enter button that when I setup the crop it changes to the crop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a copy is exactly what it says.  You are saving the image as whatever name and path you are choosing in the "Save file dialog".  It pops up after you click the "Save a copy" option.

You need to click the down arrow to the right of the `Save a copy` text and select `Save`.  This will overwrite the original with your cropped/modified version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: SOLVED. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: :) Glad to help.

Comment: Actually, I need more help. If I keep cropping a photo and spend some time on it to get it exactly how I want it - how the heck can I click the right Save a copy and it tells me "Ooops! We couldn't save that one." Huh?

Comment: I can only *guess* given the parameters you define... but before guessing, I have a suggestion.  ***Give up*** on the free solution that comes with windows and use a real editor.  Many of these are free like Paint.net and gimp but I myself carry around this horrid (legal) copy of PaintShopPro dating back 20 years (still works 100%).  As to your problem, I can guess that you are working with a file in the temp dir or cache and got cleaned before you tried to save it.. what do I know though? :)

Answer (score -1):

I found the Save button not functioning but Ctrl S allows you to rename before saving, so preserves the original too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).